# Can't figure out where I have memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm new to C and still don't really know how to work with valgrind. I'm doing a project where i need to create a function that returns a line of text from a file descriptor each time it's called using just one static variable.

> Repeated calls (e.g., using a loop) to your get_next_line() function should let
> you read the text file pointed to by the file descriptor, one line at a time.

I have come up with this but I can't find where the memory leak is:

```
char    *output(char **backup, char *rbackup, int ret, int fd)
{
    int     value;
    char    *temp;

    if (ret < 0)
        return (NULL);
    else if (ret == 0 && backup[fd] == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    value = (int)(ft_strchr(backup[fd], '\n') - backup[fd] + 1);
    rbackup = ft_substr(backup[fd], 0, value);
    temp = ft_substr(backup[fd], value, BUFFER_SIZE * BUFFER_SIZE);
    free(backup[fd]);
    if (temp[0] == '\0')
    {
        free(temp);
        temp = NULL;
    }
    backup[fd] = temp;
    return (rbackup);
}

char    *get_next_line(int fd)
{
    int         ret;
    char        buf[BUFFER_SIZE + 1];
    static char *backup[NUM_OF_FD];
    char        *rbackup;

    if (fd < 0 || fd > NUM_OF_FD)
        return (NULL);
    while (ft_strchr(backup[fd], '\n') == NULL)
    {
        ret = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        if (ret <= 0)
            break ;
        if (backup[fd] == NULL)
            backup[fd] = ft_strdup(buf);
        else
        {
            rbackup = ft_strjoin(backup[fd], buf);
            free(backup[fd]);
            backup[fd] = rbackup;
        }
    }
    return (output(backup, rbackup, ret, fd));
}
```

The ft_***functions*** are equivalent to the LibC counterparts but in case of having a bug I'll post them here:

```
void    *ft_memcpy(void *dst, const void *src, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = -1;
    if ((dst != src) && n)
        while (++i < n)
            ((unsigned char *)dst)[i] = ((unsigned char *)src)[i];
    return (dst);
}

size_t  ft_strlen(const char *s)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
    return (i);
}

char    *ft_strchr(const char *s, int c)
{
    char    chr;

    chr = (char)c;
    if (s == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (*s && *s != chr)
        s++;
    if (*s == chr)
        return ((char *)s);
    else
        return (NULL);
}

char    *ft_substr(char const *s, unsigned int start, size_t len)
{
    char    *str;

    if (!s)
        return (NULL);
    if (len > ft_strlen(s))
        len = ft_strlen(s);
    if (start > ft_strlen(s))
        len = 0;
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (len + 1));
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    str = ft_memcpy(str, &s[start], len);
    str[len] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

char    *ft_strdup(const char *s1)
{
    size_t  len;
    void    *new;

    len = ft_strlen(s1) + 1;
    new = malloc(len);
    if (new == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    return ((char *) ft_memcpy(new, s1, len));
}

char    *ft_strjoin(char const *s1, char const *s2)
{
    int     i;
    char    *str;
    size_t  size;

    if (!s1 || !s2)
        return (NULL);
    i = 0;
    size = (ft_strlen(s1) + ft_strlen(s2) + 1);
    str = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    if (!str)
        return (NULL);
    while (*s1)
        str[i++] = *s1++;
    while (*s2)
        str[i++] = *s2++;
    str[i] = '\0';
    return (str);
}

void    *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = -1;
    while (++i < len)
        ((unsigned char *)b)[i] = (unsigned char)c;
    return (b);
}
```

Is there any rookie mistake in my code?

Comment: Valgrind will tell you which allocation was leaked. Add the output to the question.

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak? That is, is there some valgrind output or some other diagnostic output that you can share with us that points to some error. That will save everyone time if you have such data.

Comment: @user17732522 unfortunately I can't as I have a M1 mac (not possible to install it)

Comment: @MiguelP Then how do you know that you have a memory leak and why are you talking about valgrind?

Comment: @kaylum yes I got an automatic evaluator error (evaluated on a different machine) but it doesn't give much info: https://pastebin.com/bzuUZgN7

Comment: @user17732522 I got automatically evaluated see above

Comment: There are bugs in `ft_substr()` — notably if `start + len > ft_strlen(str)` but neither `start` nor `len` is larger than `ft_strlen(str)`.  Then you copy memory that isn't part of `str`.  You're also allocating more memory than necessary, but that isn't as serious.

Comment: @MiguelP If it is supported try the address sanitizer or leak sanitizer instead: `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=leak` while compiling. They should give similar diagnostics to valgrind.

Comment: @user17732522 I used an cloud9's IDE with valgrind https://pastebin.com/YX4bkGts

Comment: @kaylum I used valgrind see previous reply

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the trouble with the memory allocation is that I'm limited NOT to use variable length arrays so I use a lot of memory just in case.

Comment: fix all the other errors that valgrind is giving you first - the invalid reads are a huge red flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I ran your code like this

```
int main(int a, char**b)
{
   int f = open("poop.c", O_RDONLY);
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
    char *x = get_next_line(f);
    printf("x");
    free(x);
   }
}
```

reading the first 10 lines. No leaks detected by valgrind (once I added the free in the loop)

It did moan about other things though

```
==3695== Invalid read of size 1
==3695==    at 0x109270: ft_memcpy (poop.c:26)
==3695==    by 0x1093BB: ft_substr (poop.c:70)
==3695==    by 0x109619: output (poop.c:120)
==3695==    by 0x109802: get_next_line (poop.c:155)
==3695==    by 0x109857: main (poop.c:162)
==3695==  Address 0x4a4a0a5 is 0 bytes after a block of size 101 alloc'd
==3695==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3695==    by 0x109408: ft_strdup (poop.c:81)
==3695==    by 0x109724: get_next_line (poop.c:147)
==3695==    by 0x109857: main (poop.c:162)
==3695==
==3695== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3695==    at 0x109546: output (poop.c:114)
==3695==    by 0x109802: get_next_line (poop.c:155)
==3695==    by 0x109857: main (poop.c:162)
==3695==
==3695== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3695==    at 0x109556: output (poop.c:116)
==3695==    by 0x109802: get_next_line (poop.c:155)
==3695==    by 0x109857: main (poop.c:162)
==3695==
```

seems like the uninitialized read is caused by reading an empty line.

The invalid read is here

```
((unsigned char*)dst)[i] = ((unsigned char*)src)[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Makefile for the C file, then you can add `-g` after flags in your Makefile. If you use compile the C file by `clang` or `gcc` directly, you can put `-g` after `clang` or `gcc`. Then you can get more information about your problem. `-g` is used for debugging. If you don't add that, Valgrind will only tell you which part you need to debug (like a specific function). But if you add `-g`, you will be able to know which line you need to debug with.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have a problem with:

```
static char *backup[NUM_OF_FD];
```

You check that fd is larger than NUM_OF_FD, but NUM_OF_FD would still try to index outside of the backup array.

```
if (fd < 0 || fd > NUM_OF_FD)
        return (NULL);
```

should be

```
if (fd < 0 || fd >= NUM_OF_FD)
        return (NULL);
```

Also be aware that read() can return -1, so this code could be problematic:

```
ret = read(fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE);
        buf[ret] = '\0';
        if (ret <= 0)
            break ;
```

Check the return value before using it.